# How to test if a string is basically an integer in quotes using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need a function, `is_an_integer`, where

- `"12".is_an_integer?` returns true.
- `"blah".is_an_integer?` returns false.

How can I do this in Ruby?  I would write a regex but I'm assuming there is a helper for this that I am not aware of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if string is a number in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661466/test-if-string-is-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Be careful using solutions relying on regular expressions. Benchmarks show that they run much more slowly than regular code.

Comment: There is no canonical way to turn a ruby string integer into an integer?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can use regular expressions. Here is the function with @janm's suggestions.

```
class String
    def is_i?
       !!(self =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+\z/)
    end
end
```

An edited version according to comment from @wich:

```
class String
    def is_i?
       /\A[-+]?\d+\z/ === self
    end
end
```

In case you only need to check positive numbers

```
  if !/\A\d+\z/.match(string_to_check)
      #Is not a positive number
  else
      #Is all good ..continue
  end
```

Comment: Not bad.  In Ruby you usually omit the "return" keyword if the return value is generated in the last expression in the function.  This will also return an integer value of zero, you probably want a boolean, so something like !!(str =~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/) would do that.  Then you could add it to String and leave out the argument, using "self" instead of "str", and then you could change the name to "is_i?" ...

Comment: Thanks! I have absolutely no clue about ruby conventions and practices. I just did a quick google on ruby and regular expressions to see the syntax, changed the regex to apply to the problem at hand, and tested it. It's pretty neat actually .. I may have to give it a longer look when I have more spare time.

Comment: You've got the right idea, but it doesn't match binary or hex literals (see my edited solution below).

Comment: Sarah, that's not a bug, that's a feature!

Comment: Well, given that I got two downvotes because my original solution didn't work on non-base-10 literals, I thought I'd spare him the same experience. ;)

Comment: Two comments. You can use `/regexp/ === self` instead of the `!!(self =~ /regexp/)` construct. You can use character class '\d' instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: You should use \A \Z instead of ^ $. EXAMPLE: "\n9" should not be valid!

Comment: @cintrzyk: Right, thanks. Used \z instead of \Z to match the end of the string as \Z disregards a trailing new line char.

Comment: This is quite nice answer. Just an observation, @cintrzyk noticed a place for update 4 years after the answer has been made. Now  it is updated, but all other people who used the previous answer might have used not so perfect algorithm :)

Comment: The simplest regex for an integer probably is /^\d+$/

Answer (score 203):

Well, here's the easy way:

```
class String
  def is_integer?
    self.to_i.to_s == self
  end
end

>> "12".is_integer?
=> true
>> "blah".is_integer?
=> false
```

I don't agree with the solutions that provoke an exception to convert the string - exceptions are not control flow, and you might as well do it the right way. That said, my solution above doesn't deal with non-base-10 integers. So here's the way to do with without resorting to exceptions:

```
  class String
    def integer? 
      [                          # In descending order of likeliness:
        /^[-+]?[1-9]([0-9]*)?$/, # decimal
        /^0[0-7]+$/,             # octal
        /^0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+$/,      # hexadecimal
        /^0b[01]+$/              # binary
      ].each do |match_pattern|
        return true if self =~ match_pattern
      end
      return false
    end
  end
```

Comment: Couldn't you replace `self.to_i.to_s == self` with `Integer self rescue false` ?

Comment: You could, but that would be bad form. You don't use exceptions as control flow, and no one's code should ever contain "rescue false" (or "rescue true"). Some simple gsub'ing would make my solution work for edge cases not specified by the OP.

Comment: For the record, I think inline "rescue nil" is pretty useful, at least if used with discretion.

Comment: I know a lot of people use it, and it's certainly aesthetically pleasing. To me though it's an indication that the code needs restructuring. If you're expecting an exception...it's not an exception.

Comment: I agree that exceptions should not be used as control flow.  I don't think that the requirement is that developer oriented numbers be recognized.  In non-programmer situations that could be seen as a bug, especially given that possible confusion around leading zeros and octal.  Also not consistent with to_i.

Your code doesn't handle the "-0123" case.  Once you do handle that case, you don't need a separate regexp for octal.  You can simply further by using "any?".  The only statement in your function could be "[ /re1/, /re2/, /re3/ ].any? { |re| self =~ re }", with no if clauses or returns.

Comment: I liked this solution until dealing with commas and currency. `'$1,000'.to_i.to_s == '$1,000'` fails.

Comment: might want true when there's a space, e.g. `" 1"`

Comment: I'm all in favor for this solution, except for one mostly harmless snag: `'-0'.is_integer? == false`

Comment: Thanks for this solution – I've been using it a lot. Dealing with Rails where my model IDs might also be an actual Integer, I've added a clause to return true if `value.is_a? Integer`.

Comment: I like your simple solution, a better name for it might be "is_id" - if you are checking for conversion to an id, you shouldn't have commas, whitespace, negative numbers or any of that. If you want to allow for leading zeros, a simpler regex can be tacked on: `self.to_i.to_s == self.sub(/^0+/,"")`

Comment: It's a waste of cycles to iterate on several regexes.  Rather, put them all in parens, join them with `|`, and run it once.

Comment: I think this solution adds complexity for the sake of strict adherence to a rule of thumb. In the case of using `Integer` for answering the question of whether a string contains a valid number, it's localized, robust, and easy to reason about code. The regex solution is harder to reason about and has greater potential for edge cases that need to be handled, in some cases complicating it further. The accepted answer had one such issue for several years, and this answer still has that same issue at the time of this writing. It matches strings such as "abc\n123\ndef".

Comment: `'1.0'.to_i.to_s != '1.0'`

Comment: '01'.to_i.to_s != '01'

Comment: `'+2'.is_integer?` is `false`

Answer (score 72):

You can use `Integer(str)` and see if it raises:

```
def is_num?(str)
  !!Integer(str)
rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
  false
end
```

It should be pointed out that while this does return true for `"01"`, it does not for `"09"`, simply because `09` would not be a valid integer literal. If that's not the behaviour you want, you can add `10` as a second argument to `Integer`, so the number is always interpreted as base 10.

Comment: Dude...provoking an exception just to convert a number? Exceptions are not control flow.

Comment: They aren't, but unfortunately this is the canonical way to determine "integerness" of a string in Ruby.  Methods using `#to_i` are just too broken because of it's permissiveness.

Comment: For those wondering why, Integer("09") is not valid because the "0" makes it octal, and 9 is not a valid octal number. http://osdir.com/ml/lang.ruby.general/2002-08/msg00247.html

Comment: Avdi - if to_i won't work, why not do it with regexes? Provoking an exception may be canonical (though I couldn't find a reference) but it's still a smell. I edited my answer to include a regex solution.

Comment: Sarah: you can use a Regex but in order to handle all the cases that Ruby does when parsing integers (negative numbers, hex, octal, underscores e.g. 1_000_000) it would be a very big Regex and easy to get wrong.  `Integer()` is canonical because with `Integer ()`you know for sure that anything that Ruby considers an integer literal will be accepted, and everything else will be rejected.  Duplicating what the language already gives you is arguably a worse code smell than using exceptions for control.

Comment: If you remove the "else" clause above you will actually get the numeric value back.  I would concede that the method name should probably changed then.  I still wonder what the test method is needed for. We do not have context information unfortunately.

Comment: Also beware that using `Integer(str)` will convert strings like `0x26`, so a better method to use might be `Integer(str, 10)`. The 10 will only accept base 10 numbers.

Comment: @SarahMei: @sepp2k isn't using exceptions as control flow. It'd be that way if they did something like `raise ArgumentError` and later rescued from that exception.

Comment: -1 since you shouldn't use exception for control flow. It is considered an anti-pattern in computer science!

Comment: @Rado So is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @sepp2k: +1 for funny, but maybe SO should consider which answers to reinvent the wheel with. I did a quick benchmark of my answer vs yours. Here are the results:
Benchmark result:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/40c2f51e98ae41f9249e

Source:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/12a8e22cffb4208deb21

Comment: Huzzah for a working solution to a ridiculous problem. There should be a better way to do this within ruby. The need for regexp to solve this problem is far more absurd. Complaints about using exceptions as control flow are dogmatic nonsense, this is a working solution to a problem which (while ugly) works! If you have a bullet proof regexp solution, make a PR against the ruby core!

Comment: This is a hell of a lot better than trying to work through somebody's (possibly) buggy Regex. Regarding exceptions: compare this to other languages like C# that can throw FormatException when calling Int32.Parse(). Java does something similar. Look at how Python solves this problem (basically you'll see all kinds of long complex solutions that parse manually, use regex, or throw exceptions).

Comment: @Rado regarding exception control flow "anti-pattern" in computer science--this isn't universally true. This isn't a Python question, but consider how exceptions can be used in Python: (1) error handling, (2) event notification, (3) special-case handling, (4) termination actions, (5) unusual control flows (Mark Lutz, "Learning Python", 5th ed, pg 1082-3). From Lut'z book, also check out the idiom for breaking out of multiple nested loops (using exceptions) on page 1145. And read how Exceptions Aren't Always Errors pg 1146. Ruby can do these things too. Duck typed languages aren't so dogmatic.

Comment: Note that if `str` happens to be a Float value, like `1.23`, this will return true because Integer(1.23) will convert the number to integer.

Comment: @psmith Nope. It won't.

pry(main)> Integer "1.25" rescue false
=> false

Comment: @wrzasa That's a string value. I was talking about this: `!!Integer(1.25) rescue false
 => true` (note the lack of quotes)

Comment: @psmith yes, this is a String, because this question is about strings...

Comment: @MatthewKraus Yes, it isn't universally true. They are considered anti-pattern for control-flow because they are usually more expensive. Now, are there times where they should be used? Sure - exceptional cases - hence the name. That however does not mean that they should be used all the time, especially for something like what the question asked. Check the benchmark I provided - it's evident from it that exceptions are really expensive in this case. The only time where this outperforms regex is when an exception is *not* thrown. This, in itself, tells the whole story.

Answer (score 51):

Ruby 2.6.0 enables [casting to an integer without raising an exception](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#numeric-methods-have-exception-argument), and will return `nil` if the cast fails. And since `nil` mostly behaves like `false` in Ruby, you can easily check for an integer like so:

```
if Integer(my_var, exception: false)
  # do something if my_var can be cast to an integer
end
```

Comment: This is the cleanest of all!

Comment: If you need some kind of strict type validation, this is the way to go, as `"2hey".to_i == 2` returns `true`, but `Integer("2hey", exception: false)` returns `nil`

Answer (score 27):

```
"12".match(/^(\d)+$/)      # true
"1.2".match(/^(\d)+$/)     # false
"dfs2".match(/^(\d)+$/)    # false
"13422".match(/^(\d)+$/)   # true
```

Comment: It doesn't return `true` and `false` but `MatchData` instances and `nil`

Comment: It is not what it returns, but if it matches

Comment: Wrap it with `!!` or use `present?` if you need a boolean `!!( "12".match /^(\d)+$/ )` or `"12".match(/^(\d)+$/).present?` (the latter requiring Rails/activesupport)

Comment: This regular expression does not take a sign into account: negative numbers are valid _integer numbers_ too. You're now testing for valid _natural numbers_ or zero.

Answer (score 25):

You can do a one liner:

```
str = ...
int = Integer(str) rescue nil

if int
  int.times {|i| p i}
end
```

or even

```
int = Integer(str) rescue false
```

Depending on what you are trying to do you can also directly use a begin end block with rescue clause:

```
begin
  str = ...
  i = Integer(str)

  i.times do |j|
    puts j
  end
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "Not an int, doing something else"
end
```

Comment: With regard to the topic "exception as control flow": since we do not know how the method at hand is to be used we cannot really judge whether exceptions would fit or not.  If the string is input and it is required to be an integer, then providing a non integer would warrant an exception.  Although then maybe the handling is not in the same method and we would probably just do Integer(str).times {|i| puts i} or whatever.

Answer (score 8):

```
class String
  def integer?
    Integer(self)
    return true
  rescue ArgumentError
    return false
  end
end
```

1. It isn't prefixed with `is_`. I find that silly on questionmark methods, I like `"04".integer?` a lot better than `"foo".is_integer?`.
2. It uses the sensible solution by sepp2k, which passes for `"01"` and such.
3. Object oriented, yay.

Comment: +1 for naming it #integer?, -1 for cluttering up String with it :-P

Comment: Where else would it go? `integer?("a string")` ftl.

Comment: `String#integer?` is the kind of common patch that every Ruby coder and their cousin likes to add to the language, leading to codebases with three different subtly incompatible implementations and unexpected breakage.  I learned this the hard way on large Ruby projects.

Comment: Same comment as above: exceptions shouldn't be used for control flow.

Comment: Downside: this solution is wasting one conversion.

Answer (score 8):

The Best and Simple way is using `Float`

```
val = Float "234" rescue nil

Float "234" rescue nil #=> 234.0

Float "abc" rescue nil #=> nil

Float "234abc" rescue nil #=> nil

Float nil rescue nil #=> nil

Float "" rescue nil #=> nil
```

`Integer` is also good but it will return `0` for `Integer nil`

Comment: I'm glad I noticed your answer.  Otherwise I would have gone with "Integer" when I needed "Float".

Comment: This is simple but the best answer! We don't really need fancy patch to String class in most of the cases. This works best for me!

Comment: (Float(value) rescue false) ? Float(value).to_s==value ? Float(value) : Integer(value) : value

Answer (score 7):

I prefer:

config/initializers/string.rb

```
class String
  def number?
    Integer(self).is_a?(Integer)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    false
  end
end
```

and then:

```
[218] pry(main)> "123123123".number?
=> true
[220] pry(main)> "123 123 123".gsub(/ /, '').number?
=> true
[222] pry(main)> "123 123 123".number?
=> false
```

or check phone number:

```
"+34 123 456 789 2".gsub(/ /, '').number?
```

Answer (score 5):

Personally I like the exception approach although I would make it a little more terse:

```
class String
  def integer?(str)
    !!Integer(str) rescue false
  end
end
```

However, as others have already stated, this doesn't work with Octal strings.

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler way could be

```
/(\D+)/.match('1221').nil? #=> true
/(\D+)/.match('1a221').nil? #=> false
/(\D+)/.match('01221').nil? #=> true
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  def isint(str)
    return !!(str =~ /^[-+]?[1-9]([0-9]*)?$/)
  end
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful. Instead provide an explanation of how it works and why it's the appropriate answer. We want to educate for the future so the solution is understood, not solve the immediate question.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 2.4 has [`Regexp#match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F): (with a `?`)

```
def integer?(str)
  /\A[+-]?\d+\z/.match? str
end
```

For older Ruby versions, there's [`Regexp#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D). And although direct use of the case equality operator should generally be avoided, it looks very clean here:

```
def integer?(str)
  /\A[+-]?\d+\z/ === str
end

integer? "123"    # true
integer? "-123"   # true
integer? "+123"   # true

integer? "a123"   # false
integer? "123b"   # false
integer? "1\n2"   # false
```

Answer (score 3):

This might not be suitable for all cases simplely using:

```
"12".to_i   => 12
"blah".to_i => 0
```

might also do for some.

If it's a number and not 0 it will return a number. If it returns 0 it's either a string or 0.

Comment: Works but it's not recommended, since ```"12blah".to_i => 12```. This might cause some trouble in weird scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

```
# /initializers/string.rb
class String
  IntegerRegex = /^(\d)+$/

  def integer?
    !!self.match(IntegerRegex)
  end
end

# any_model_or_controller.rb
'12345'.integer? # true
'asd34'.integer? # false
```

And here's how it works:

- `/^(\d)+$/`is *regex* expression for finding digits in any string. You can test your regex expressions and results at http://rubular.com/.
- We save it in a constant `IntegerRegex` to avoid unnecessary memory allocation everytime we use it in the method.
- `integer?` is an interrogative method which should return `true` or `false`.
- `match` is a method on string which matches the occurrences as per the given regex expression in argument and return the matched values or `nil`.
- `!!` converts the result of `match` method into equivalent boolean.
- And declaring the method in existing `String` class is monkey patching, which doesn't change anything in existing String functionalities, but just adds another method named `integer?` on any String object.

Comment: Could you add a little explanation to this please?

Comment: @stef - I've done the same. Please let me know if you have any query still.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @rado's answer above one could also use a ternary statement to force the return of true or false booleans without the use of double bangs. Granted, the double logical negation version is more terse, but probably harder to read for newcomers (like me).

```
class String
  def is_i?
     self =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+\z/ ? true : false
  end
end
```

Comment: Consider that using regular expressions forces Ruby to do a lot more work so if this is used in a loop it'll slow the code. Anchoring the expression helps, but regex are still significantly slower.

Answer (score 1):

For more generalised cases (including numbers with decimal point),
you can try the following method:

```
def number?(obj)
  obj = obj.to_s unless obj.is_a? String
  /\A[+-]?\d+(\.[\d]+)?\z/.match(obj)
end
```

You can test this method in an irb session:

```
(irb)
>> number?(7)
=> #<MatchData "7" 1:nil>
>> !!number?(7)
=> true
>> number?(-Math::PI)
=> #<MatchData "-3.141592653589793" 1:".141592653589793">
>> !!number?(-Math::PI)
=> true
>> number?('hello world')
=> nil
>> !!number?('hello world')
=> false
```

For a detailed explanation of the regex involved here, check out [this blog article](https://medium.com/@Taiga/number-validation-with-regex-ruby-393954e46797#.5m579y9t2) :)

Comment: Isn't necessary to call `obj.is_a? String` because [String#to_s](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_s) will return itself, which I guess doesn't require too much processing compared with the `.is_a?` call. This way, you'll be making only one call in this line instead of one or two.
Also, you could include directly `!!` inside the `number?` method, because by convention, a method name that ends with `?` is supposed to return a boolean value. Regards!

Answer (score -3):

One liner in `string.rb`

```
def is_integer?; true if Integer(self) rescue false end
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if this was around when this question is asked but 
for anyone that stumbles across this post, the simplest way is:

```
var = "12"
var.is_a?(Integer) # returns false
var.is_a?(String) # returns true

var = 12
var.is_a?(Integer) # returns true
var.is_a?(String) # returns false
```

`.is_a?` will work with any object.

Comment: That's not what the original question is asking. OP wants to know if the string is an integer also. 

e.g.

`"12".is_an_integer? == true`
`"not12".is_an_integer? == false`
`12.is_an_integer? == true`