# Ruby: checking if a string can be converted to an integer

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test if a string is basically an integer in quotes using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby)

```
"1"
"one"
```

The first string is a number, and I can just say to_i to get an integer.
The second string is also a number, but I can't directly call to_i to get the desired number.

How do I check whether I can successfully convert using to_i or not?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's an `Integer` method that unlike `to_i` will raise an exception if it can't convert:

```
>> Integer("1")
=> 1
>> Integer("one")
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "one"
```

If you don't want to raise an exception since Ruby 2.6 you can do this:

```
Integer("one", exception: false)
```

If your string can be converted you'll get the integer, otherwise `nil`.

The `Integer` method is the most comprehensive check I know of in Ruby (e.g. "09" won't convert because the leading zero makes it octal and 9 is an invalid digit). Covering all these cases with regular expressions is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: As of Ruby 2.6.0, the `rescue nil` can be avoided by using `Integer("one", exception: false)`. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54022892/4469336

Comment: Old answer but I just stumbled across it and figured I'd point out that `'09'` doesn't have to error, at least anymore: `Integer()` takes an optional second positional argument for `base`, so `Integer('09', 10)` would give you `9`