# Apply all hash's value to integer if it could

Tags: ruby

I want to get the `buy_house_params`, if values like "123" can be `123`

if value is `abc` then keep it as original.

```
buy_house_params.each { |key, value| buy_house_params[key]=value.to_i }
```

But I still get the string type integer

```
{"user_id"=>"", "age"=>"28", "gender"=>"male", "monthly_income"=>"48000"}
```

Comment: Rails parses string into integers automatically based in activemodel information if that's your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class String
  def is_number?
    true if Float(self) rescue false
  end
end

buy_house_params = {"user_id"=>"", "age"=>"28", "gender"=>"male", "monthly_income"=>"48000"}
buy_house_params.each{|k, v| buy_house_params[k] = v.to_i if v.is_number? }
=> {"user_id"=>"", "age"=>28, "gender"=>"male", "monthly_income"=>48000}
```

It will test to see if each hashmap value is numeric before converting it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expresion parse the string only if it matches the desired format: quoted integers.

```
class String
    def is_i?
       !!(self =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+\z/)
    end
end
```

Answered here:

[Test if a string is basically an integer in quotes using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby)

Or you can test if it's an integer:

```
>> Integer "1"
=> 1
>> Integer "one"
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "one"
```

[Ruby: checking if a string can be converted to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577783/ruby-checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-an-integer)