# String#to_i with no match

Tags: ruby, string, casting

`String#to_i` returns `0` when the string does not match any number characters, and I understand that many people including myself consider this unnatural and would rather expect `nil` to be returned in such case. But Matz designed it otherwise. What is the best way to distinguish strings that actually are `"0"` (or `"00"`, etc.) from strings that do not include number characters?

Comment: You might want to check out this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
Integer('')                         # =>  #<ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer: ""> 
Integer('0')                       # => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this `i = s.to_i ; i = nil if i == 0 && s != '0'`. If you need it often - either monkeypatch to_i or just add better_to_i.