# How to search by id or name in Active Record using meta search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

I have an model, say:

```
class MyModel <ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
end
```

I want to search this model using meta_search (https://github.com/ernie/meta_search), 
How can I search by id or name?

I tried this but does not work:

```
MyModel.search(id_equals_or_name_contains: 'sample text')
```

The meta search document says they don't support different match type (https://github.com/ernie/meta_search#ored-conditions), so How should I achieve this?

Comment: although it is not a good way but you can simply try `arr= MyModel.search(id_equals: '').concat(MyModel.search(name_contains: '')).uniq`

Comment: Is there a reason you are restricted to meta search? Is using a bit of SQL an option?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the sample text to either be an integer or a string? If so you could implement a simple conditional using the function described here: [Test if a string is basically an integer in quotes using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby)

```
s = 'sample text'
if !!(s =~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/)
  MyModel.search(id_equals: s.to_i)
else
  MyModel.search(name_contains: s)
end
```