# String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

I wrote the basic codes below

```
puts ' Hi there , what is your favorite number ? '
number = gets.chomp
puts number + ' is beautiful '
puts 1 + number.to_i + 'is way better'
```

But when I run it,I get the error "String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)". How do I correct this error please?

Answer (score 22):

You cannot add a String to a number. You *can* add a number to a String, since it is coerced to a String:

```
'1' + 1
# => "11"
1 + 1
# => 2
1 + '1'
# TypeError!
```

Since I suspect you want to show the result of adding 1 to your number, you should explicitly [cast it to string](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s):

```
puts (1 + number.to_i).to_s + ' is way better'
```

or, use [string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation):

```
puts "#{1 + number.to_i} is way better"
```

Answer (score 2):

**String can't be coerced into Integer** usually happens, when you try to add a string to a number. since you want to add 1 to your number and concatenate it with a string "is way better". you have to explicitly cast the result you got from adding 1 to your number to a string and concatenate it with your string "is way better".

you can update your code to this:

```
puts (1 + number.to_i).to_s + " " + 'is way better'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the results of entering 'xyz' as an input surprising.

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby) for determining if your input string is a number may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers are natural numbers:

```
number = gets.chomp
puts "#{number} is beautiful ", "#{number.succ} is way better"
```

Comment: Although succ doesn't understand negative numbers