# Rails OR condition inside where with same input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following active record query:

```
User.where(["id = ? OR token = ?", params[:id], params[:id]]).first
```

Here, `params[:id] = 9MrEflgr`

**PROBLEM**

As per logic, `params[:id]` can be numeric **id** or alphanumeric **token**.

I want to get something like `User.find_by_id_or_token(params[:id])` in where clause.

Here, since the `params[:id]` starts with '9', so active record gives me user with id 9 instead of checking for token field. How to avoid this?

Comment: Figure out what `params[:id]` is first?

Comment: What's wrong with `User.where(["id = ? OR token = ?", params[:id], params[:id]]).first` ? Why do you want to get to `find_by_id_or_token`?

Comment: @GavinMiller It gives me user with id 9 since `"9MrEflgr".to_i` is 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment mentioned, you need to check if the params is an integer. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby) has good suggestions on how to do that (where you can implement `is_integer?` below).

```
if params[:id].is_integer?
  User.where(["id = ? OR token = ?", params[:id], params[:id]]).first
else
  User.where(["token = ?", params[:id]]).first
end
```

Comment: `params[:id]` will always be a string.  You'll need to cast it first.

Comment: @japed that is why @AbM suggested implementing an `is_integer?` method (see the linked SO question in answer)

Comment: [AbM](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2697183/abm) Thanks for replying. I have already tried this fix. But, I was searching for an one liner solution.

Comment: Also, as mentioned in the comments of the [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1235891/2968762), `"01".to_i.to_s is not equal to "01"`

Comment: Are you expecting an `id` to be passed as `"01"`? If so, try using the [regex solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18129961/2697183)

Comment: @AbM I'm expecting token may be starting with 0, which is rare but a possibility. Apart from this, is there a possible single line code?

Comment: Then you're fine. If you implement `to_i.to_s` for checking `is_integer?`, then if the `params[:id]` starts with `"0"`, it will execute the `else` block, and only look for users based on the `token`. The one liner will still need to check `is_integer?`