# How can I tell if x.to_i is really 0 (zero)?

Tags: ruby

```
"0".to_i == 0
```

also:

```
"abcdefg".to_i == 0
```

I want to make sure the string I'm parsing really is just a number (0 included).

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby

Comment: Are you sure "how to tell `x.to_i` is `0`" is what you want to ask? As you did, `"abcdefg".to_i == 0` tells you exactly that.

Comment: Pretty easy to understand that "9".to_i == 9, and "0".to_i == 0, and that "xyz".to_i == 0 is what was throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def string_is_integer?(string)
  !string.match(/^(\d)+$/).nil? # \d looks for digits
end

def string_is_float?(string)
  !string.match(/^(\d)+\.(\d)+$/).nil?
end

def string_is_number?(string)
  string_is_integer?(string) || string_is_float?(string)
end
```

Or, if you don't mind:

```
def string_is_number?(string)
  begin
    true if Float(string)
  rescue ArgumentError       
  end || false
end
```

Comment: I went with a variation on your last answer:

    def is_number? string
      true if Float(string) rescue false
    end

Comment: @Ashbury, you should always rescue exceptions explicitly. here, we only want to rescue the `ArgumentError`. but if you use `rescue` by itself, it will rescue `StandardError`. plus, in your version, the code might return `nil` if a new version of Ruby decided to return `nil` from `Float(string)`. my versions ensure that a boolean is returned in all cases and an exception is thrown when something unexpected happens.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'll use yours.

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer("0").zero? rescue false
# => true
Integer("1").zero? rescue false
# => false
Integer("abcdefg").zero? rescue false
# => false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_zero?(string)   
  (Integer(string) rescue 1).zero?
end     

is_zero? "0"           #=> true
is_zero? "00000"       #=> true
is_zero? "0cat"        #=> false
is_zero? "1"           #=> false
is_zero? "-0"          #=> true
is_zero? "0_000"       #=> true
is_zero? "0x00"        #=> true
is_zero? "0b00000000"  #=> true
```

Several of these examples illustrate why it's preferable to use [Kernel#Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) rather than a regular expression.

Comment: I'd prefer `Integer(string).zero? rescue false`

Comment: @Stefan, me too. After seeing sawa's answer I decided to leave it to make the point about `Integer` vs regex.

Comment: Note to self: check answers before posting comments.

Answer (score 0):

First test if the string is integer or not and then match

```
def is_i?(x)
   !!(x =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+\z/)
end

def is_zero?(x)
  return is_i?(x) && x.to_i == 0
end

# is_zero?("0") will return true
# is_zero?("abcde") will return false
```

Or you can put these methods in `String` class like this

```
class String
    def is_i?
       !!(self =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+\z/)
    end

    def is_zero?
        self.is_i? && self.to_i == 0
    end
end

"0".is_zero? # true
"abcde".is_zero? # false
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make sure the string I'm parsing really is just a number.

There are two steps involved:

1. Parsing, i.e. converting the string into a number
2. Validation, i.e. checking if the string actually is a number

The built-in conversion functions like [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) and [`Float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) already perform both steps: they return a numeric result if the string is valid and raise an error otherwise.

Using these functions just for validation and discarding the return value is wasteful. Instead, use the return value and handle the exception, e.g.:

```
begin
  puts 'Enter a number:'
  number = Float(gets)
rescue
  puts 'Not a valid number'
  retry
end
# do something with number
```

or something like:

```
def parse_number(string)
  Float(string) rescue nil
end

number = parse_number(some_string)
if number
  # do something with number
else
  # not a number
end
```