# How to use flow control to request the user inputs an integer as opposed to a string

Tags: ruby, if-statement, integer, flow-control

My program asks a user for a number. I'm working with flow control to ensure that the user enters only a number, and if the user enters anything other than a number, the program prompts the user to "Please enter a number". Even when the user enters a number, the flow control statement asking the user to "Please enter a number" runs.

I'm not getting any error messages, but one of my `if`/`else` statements must have inappropriate syntax. I've done research about what "variable" should be set to to achieve the desired output, but I must not have the appropriate boolean value.

```
puts "Enter a number."
variable = gets.chomp
variable = variable.to_i

if variable != Integer
 puts "Please enter a number."
elsif variable == Integer 
 puts "Thank you. Your number is #{variable}."
end
```

Even when I actually enter a number in the terminal, I only get "Please enter a number." I expect that when I enter a number, I will get "`Thank you. Your number is #{variable}.`"

Comment: By "...to ensure that the user enters only a number", I assume you mean, "...to ensure that the user enters the string representation of an integer". Being as precise in your language as in your code will pay dividends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to compare Integer and get true is comparing Integer with Integer:

```
Integer == Integer
# true
```

What you need in that case is to use [`Object#is_a?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) which *returns true if class is the class of obj, or if class is one of the superclasses of obj or modules included in obj*:

```
module M;    end
class A
  include M
end
class B < A; end
class C < B; end

b = B.new
b.is_a? A          #=> true
b.is_a? B          #=> true
b.is_a? C          #=> false
b.is_a? M          #=> true
```

That allows you to check if the object is Integer "based", but, notice that you're redefining `variable` to its `to_i` version, which will return an Integer always.

You could use [`String#match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) to check if the value entered by the user matches a number (positive or negative Integer):

```
unless variable.match?(/^-?\d*$/)
  ...
end
```

Comment: ➜  RubyPractice ruby flow-control-practice.rb
        Enter a number.
        er
        flow-control-practice.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `match?' for 0:Integer 
        (NoMethodError)

Comment: I just tried using "unless" in the way you have above, and that error was outputted on the terminal

Comment: Sorry, isn't because of the `unless` addition, it's because you're calling `to_i` on `variable`. Remove that part and try again, match? is a String method.

Comment: I think that worked. I had to reverse the logic on my flow control statment. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask what (/^-?\d*$/) does?

Comment: I assume that is just checking to see that the variable is a string method.

Comment: That's a regular expression to check if the whole string is a number which may contain a dash at the beginning in case of being negative.

Answer (score 2):

The problem are `!= and ==` methods.

For a better way to check if a String can be converted to a valid Integer refer to:
[Test if a string is basically an integer in quotes using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby)

You'de better use an `if else statement`.

If you add an is_integer? method to the String class as shown in the link above (but you do not have to is just a way) you can check like this:

```
var_string = gets.chomp
if var_string.is_integer?
  do_something
else
  do_something_else
end
```

Comment: Ah, ok. So I could just use

Comment: if variable.is_integer? ?

Comment: @cwhitt91 Yes, I edited the answer I hope should be clearer.